# Add multiple flows to a table in opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I want to add multiple flows to a table with a single curl call. Is it possible ??

PFB the Flows which is supposed to be pushed to table 0. Currently, Flow1 is pushed and Flow2 is been pushed one after other using 2 curl call.

Can these 2 Flows be merged to single xml in ODL ?? It is possible is ONOS.

1) Flow 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:service">
  <barrier>false</barrier>
  <node xmlns:inv="urn:opendaylight:inventory">/inv:nodes/inv:node[inv:id="openflow:7"]</node>
  <match>
      <ethernet-match>
          <ethernet-type>
            <type>0x800</type>
          </ethernet-type>
      </ethernet-match>
  </match>
  <instructions>
    <instruction>
      <order>0</order>
      <go-to-table>
        <table_id>1</table_id>
      </go-to-table>
    </instruction>
  </instructions>
  <priority>0</priority>
  <strict>false</strict>
  <table_id>0</table_id>
</input>
```

2) Flow 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<input xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:service">
  <barrier>false</barrier>
  <node xmlns:inv="urn:opendaylight:inventory">/inv:nodes/inv:node[inv:id="openflow:7"]</node>
  <match>
      <ethernet-match>
          <ethernet-type>
            <type>0x86dd</type>
          </ethernet-type>
      </ethernet-match>
  </match>
  <instructions>
    <instruction>
      <order>0</order>
      <go-to-table>
        <table_id>2</table_id>
      </go-to-table>
    </instruction>
  </instructions>
  <priority>0</priority>
  <strict>false</strict>
  <table_id>0</table_id>
</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot merge them in ODL.

Comment: So what is the best way to add Multiple flows for a table ??

Comment: @uday, add each flow seperately, with a seperate request. However note that you are not trying to add the flows to the same table, judging from your xmls.

Comment: I am adding Flow's to the same table (table Id 0 ). The Match(based on eth Type ) and the instruction is different.                                                                                          1) Match : IPV4 packet, Action: Go to table 1                                                        2) Match : IPV6 packet, Action Go to table 2.                                                                          So i am trying to add Flows to the same table.

Comment: @uday oops, sorry, I saw the Goto instruction instead.